# Symfony Form: CollectionType with different prototypes

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

Is there a way to build a form with CollectionType with a possibility to add different prototypes.

Background: I want to build a "Pagebuilder".
The functionality is like this one, but i have to integrate it into an existing app.

[image: Pagebuilder with SuluCMF]

So i have to add different prototypes. The different prototypes can be switched with the select field.

There should be multiple forms with different form fields.
E.G. one for

- Link to a Product
- A Single WYSIWYG element
- an image with metadata
- etc...

The Form should be as simple as possible for the user.
So i need the possibility to add multiple prototypes.

Is this already possible (and how)?

Comment: Do you want to integrate that form into the Sulu Admin? Or is that a complete separate application, and the screenshot is only a visualization of what you want?

Comment: It's only a visualisation. I like the one by Sulu and want to be able to add n different types in a row while persisting order and the different types. My biggest concern so far is the validation for the different Types.

I can do this manually bute had the hope to automate it somehow like in the CollectionType.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Although your question was about CollectionType, after looking more closely into your screenshot, I think you just need to create one master form with multiple child forms, and show appropriate child form (using javascript) depending on user selection.

Comment: But how do i accomplish mixed types? So it validates the forms (which are added with js using the prototype) by the correct subform?

Comment: You don't need to use prototype feature just because your form is dynamic and some parts of it are hidden/shown by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using CollectionType (I don't see a reason for that in your screenshot), then you can do something like:

```
    $builder->add('entity1', CollectionType::class, [
        'label' => 'entity.recipe.entity1',
        'entry_type' => \AppBundle\Form\Type\Entity1Type::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'prototype_name' => '__EntityId__',
        'entry_options'  => ['required'  => false],
        ]);

    $builder->add('entity2', CollectionType::class, [
        'label' => 'entity.recipe.entity2',
        'entry_type' => \AppBundle\Form\Type\Entity2Type::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'prototype_name' => '__EntityId__',
        'entry_options'  => ['required'  => false],
        ]);
...
```

Add as many entity types as you want, and each will be a collection with zero or more items.